# Should deferred LINQ statements inside lock() give a compilation warning?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, locking

Should Visual Studio give a warning if non-executed LINQ statements are inside a lock? The problem is that LINQ statements returning IEnumerables are postponed, thus they can be executed after the lock when the LINQ result is being read.

The following code reproduces the scenario with a Collection-was-modified exception:

```
private static readonly List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>()
  {
      new KeyValuePair<string, double>("A", 0),
      new KeyValuePair<string, double>("B", 1),
      new KeyValuePair<string, double>("C", 2)
  };

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      new Timer(Write, null, 0, 1);
      new Timer(Read, null, 0, 1);
      Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
  }

  private static void Write(object state)
  {
      lock (list)
      {
          for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
          {
              list[i] = new KeyValuePair<string, double>(list[i].Key, list[i].Value + 1);
          }
      }
  }

  private static void Read(object state)
  {
      IEnumerable<string> tempList;

      lock (list)
      {
          tempList = list.Select(it => it.Key + ":" + it.Value); // LINQ not always executed here
      }

      foreach (var s in tempList) // may trigger an Exception: Collection was modified
      {
          Console.WriteLine(s);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

No.

1. The compiler can't necessarily know whether or not it's possible to execute the query outside of the scope of the `lock` statement.  It would depend on the specific heuristics it used, but the odds of both false positives and false negatives are likely to be significant.
2. It's not necessarily wrong to expose a `LINQ` query outside of a `lock` statement.  It often would be, but not *universally* so.

   For example, even in *the example that you gave*, if your `Write` function replaces `list` with a new `List`, rather than mutating it, then *your code would be safe, and would work properly.  Letting a LINQ query that's root data source is immutable (or any other type of `IEnumerable<T>` that can safely be iterated outside of a critical section, of which there are lots) is a safe operation.
3. It's not an *extremely* common problem that a significant portion of developers are likely to come across.

This would be, at best, something to look at for a warning in a 3rd party code analysis tool (even there it likely wouldn't make the cut for the given reasons).  It would certainly have no place in the compiler's suite of warnings.